# Google Play Services Message Handling with Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services

I'm looking for some idea of how to handle Reliable Messages in Google Play Services with libGDX. So far I've been using it like this: I was waiting for message with `OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener`, setting an outside `byte[]` array to the message received, changing a flag that suggests that new message arrived to true, getting that message in my libGDX class using methods from interface, setting `newMessage` flag again to false, handling message, and so again waiting for new one

```
private OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener mMessageRecievedHandler = new OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(@NonNull RealTimeMessage realTimeMessage) {

            //Handle received message here


            byte[] message = realTimeMessage.getMessageData();

            /*byte tbye[] = message;
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(tbye);
            if(bb.getFloat() == 1884) {
                Log.d("MESSAGETEST", "Message received in anL : " + debugIntL);
                debugIntL++;
            } */

            byteArray = message;

            newMessageFlag = true;
        }
    };

@Override
    public boolean getNewMessageFlag() {
        return newMessageFlag;
    }


@Override
    public byte[] getMessage() {
        newMessageFlag = false;
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Libgdx class:

```
@Override
    public void render (float delta) {
    ...
    checkForNewMessage();
    ...
   }

private void checkForNewMessage() {

    if(game.customHandler.getNewMessageFlag()) {
        handleMessage(); // handling message here
    }

}

private void handleMessage() {

        byte[] message = game.customHandler.getMessage();

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(message);

        float typeOfMessage = bb.getFloat();



        if(typeOfMessage == NEW_UNIT_MESSAGE) {

            Gdx.app.log("MESSAGETEST", "Message received in gdx : " + debugInt);
            debugInt++;
            ...
           }
       }
```

But the result is, when uncommenting the code in `OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener` and adding similar log to my `handleMessage();` that some messages are skipped between receiving it in listener and checking for new in my libGDX class, I don't know why, maybe because some `render` calls take longer to do everything inside and it skips through one check call when there's significant number of those in small amount of time 
[image]

On the image you can see that first log is from `OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener`, which receives every message, but the second one is from `handleMessage`, and at 251 there it wasn't called, so `handleMessage` just skipped this message and went to the next one.

So here's my question, what's good way to handle those messages so that I won't skip any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if anyone has the same problem i think i found the solution, there's been no problems with that so far, i'll edit this answer if it turns out to have some problems.

Anyway, the solution is as follows, I completely abandoned the idea of checking for new message with flags, and then handling it, instead in main class with `OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener`  i created `private List<byte[]> byteArrayList`and changed listener to:

```
private OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener mMessageRecievedHandler = new OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(@NonNull RealTimeMessage realTimeMessage) {

            //Handle received message here


            byte[] message = realTimeMessage.getMessageData();

            byteArrayList.add(message);

        }
    };


@Override
public List<byte[]> getArrayOfMessages() {
    return byteArrayList;
}
```

Then in the libGDX class instead of `checkForNewMessage()` in `render` method i just put the `handleMessage()`there which looks like this

```
private void handleMessage() {

        if(!game.customHandler.getArrayOfMessages().isEmpty() && game.customHandler.getArrayOfMessages() != null) {

            byte[] message = game.customHandler.getArrayOfMessages().get(0);
            game.customHandler.getArrayOfMessages().remove(0);

            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(message);

             // Rest of handling message...
```

This way  it won't skip anything, because every message is inside a `ArrayList`, and `handleMessage()` handles every message that is inside of it one by one.

Comment: Looks like a nice improvement.  Thanks for sharing.